# Android Studio: Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

in android studio, when i want generate signed apk, Leads to the following error:

`Error:Error: Expected resource of type styleable [ResourceType]`

this Class is: https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

How can I fix the error?

`PagerSlidingTabStrip` class:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.res.TypedArray;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
    import android.graphics.Typeface;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Parcel;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
    import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Locale;

    public class PagerSlidingTabStrip extends HorizontalScrollView {

        public interface IconTabProvider {
            public int getPageIconResId(int position);
        }

        // @formatter:off
        private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[] {
            android.R.attr.textSize,
            android.R.attr.textColor
        };
        // @formatter:on

        private LinearLayout.LayoutParams defaultTabLayoutParams;
        private LinearLayout.LayoutParams expandedTabLayoutParams;

        private final PageListener pageListener = new PageListener();
        public OnPageChangeListener delegatePageListener;

        private LinearLayout tabsContainer;
        private ViewPager pager;

        private int tabCount;

        private int currentPosition = 0;
        private float currentPositionOffset = 0f;

        private Paint rectPaint;
        private Paint dividerPaint;

        private int indicatorColor = 0xFF666666;
        private int underlineColor = 0x1A000000;
        private int dividerColor = 0x1A000000;

        private boolean shouldExpand = false;
        private boolean textAllCaps = true;

        private int scrollOffset = 52;
        private int indicatorHeight = 8;
        private int underlineHeight = 2;
        private int dividerPadding = 12;
        private int tabPadding = 24;
        private int dividerWidth = 1;

        private int tabTextSize = 12;
        private int tabTextColor = 0xFF666666;
        private Typeface tabTypeface = null;
        private int tabTypefaceStyle = Typeface.BOLD;

        private int lastScrollX = 0;

        private int tabBackgroundResId = R.drawable.background_tab;

        private Locale locale;

        public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public PagerSlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

            setFillViewport(true);
            setWillNotDraw(false);

            tabsContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
            tabsContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            tabsContainer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            addView(tabsContainer);

            DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

            scrollOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, scrollOffset, dm);
            indicatorHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, indicatorHeight, dm);
            underlineHeight = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, underlineHeight, dm);
            dividerPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerPadding, dm);
            tabPadding = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, tabPadding, dm);
            dividerWidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dividerWidth, dm);
            tabTextSize = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, tabTextSize, dm);

            // get system attrs (android:textSize and android:textColor)

            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, ATTRS);

            tabTextSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(0, tabTextSize);
            tabTextColor = a.getColor(1, tabTextColor);

            a.recycle();

            // get custom attrs

            a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip);

            indicatorColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorColor, indicatorColor);
            underlineColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineColor, underlineColor);
            dividerColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerColor, dividerColor);
            indicatorHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsIndicatorHeight, indicatorHeight);
            underlineHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsUnderlineHeight, underlineHeight);
            dividerPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsDividerPadding, dividerPadding);
            tabPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabPaddingLeftRight, tabPadding);
            tabBackgroundResId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabBackground, tabBackgroundResId);
            shouldExpand = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsShouldExpand, shouldExpand);
            scrollOffset = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsScrollOffset, scrollOffset);
            textAllCaps = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTextAllCaps, textAllCaps);

            a.recycle();

            rectPaint = new Paint();
            rectPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            rectPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

            dividerPaint = new Paint();
            dividerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            dividerPaint.setStrokeWidth(dividerWidth);

            defaultTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            expandedTabLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);

            if (locale == null) {
                locale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
            }
        }

        public void setViewPager(ViewPager pager) {
            this.pager = pager;

            if (pager.getAdapter() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("ViewPager does not have adapter instance.");
            }

            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageListener);

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public void setOnPageChangeListener(OnPageChangeListener listener) {
            this.delegatePageListener = listener;
        }

        public void notifyDataSetChanged() {

            tabsContainer.removeAllViews();

            tabCount = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

                if (pager.getAdapter() instanceof IconTabProvider) {
                    addIconTab(i, ((IconTabProvider) pager.getAdapter()).getPageIconResId(i));
                } else {
                    addTextTab(i, pager.getAdapter().getPageTitle(i).toString());
                }

            }

            updateTabStyles();

            getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                        getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    } else {
                        getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }

                    currentPosition = pager.getCurrentItem();
                    scrollToChild(currentPosition, 0);
                }
            });

        }

        private void addTextTab(final int position, String title) {

            TextView tab = new TextView(getContext());
            tab.setText(title);
            tab.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tab.setSingleLine();

            addTab(position, tab);
        }

        private void addIconTab(final int position, int resId) {

            ImageButton tab = new ImageButton(getContext());
            tab.setImageResource(resId);

            addTab(position, tab);

        }

        private void addTab(final int position, View tab) {
            tab.setFocusable(true);
            tab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    pager.setCurrentItem(position);
                }
            });

            tab.setPadding(tabPadding, 0, tabPadding, 0);
            tabsContainer.addView(tab, position, shouldExpand ? expandedTabLayoutParams : defaultTabLayoutParams);
        }

        private void updateTabStyles() {

            for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {

                View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);

                v.setBackgroundResource(tabBackgroundResId);

                if (v instanceof TextView) {

                    TextView tab = (TextView) v;
                    tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tabTextSize);
                    tab.setTypeface(tabTypeface, tabTypefaceStyle);
                    tab.setTextColor(tabTextColor);

                    // setAllCaps() is only available from API 14, so the upper case is made manually if we are on a
                    // pre-ICS-build
                    if (textAllCaps) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                            tab.setAllCaps(true);
                        } else {
                            tab.setText(tab.getText().toString().toUpperCase(locale));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        private void scrollToChild(int position, int offset) {

            if (tabCount == 0) {
                return;
            }

            int newScrollX = tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getLeft() + offset;

            if (position > 0 || offset > 0) {
                newScrollX -= scrollOffset;
            }

            if (newScrollX != lastScrollX) {
                lastScrollX = newScrollX;
                scrollTo(newScrollX, 0);
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            if (isInEditMode() || tabCount == 0) {
                return;
            }

            final int height = getHeight();

            // draw indicator line

            rectPaint.setColor(indicatorColor);

            // default: line below current tab
            View currentTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition);
            float lineLeft = currentTab.getLeft();
            float lineRight = currentTab.getRight();

            // if there is an offset, start interpolating left and right coordinates between current and next tab
            if (currentPositionOffset > 0f && currentPosition < tabCount - 1) {

                View nextTab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(currentPosition + 1);
                final float nextTabLeft = nextTab.getLeft();
                final float nextTabRight = nextTab.getRight();

                lineLeft = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabLeft + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineLeft);
                lineRight = (currentPositionOffset * nextTabRight + (1f - currentPositionOffset) * lineRight);
            }

            canvas.drawRect(lineLeft, height - indicatorHeight, lineRight, height, rectPaint);

            // draw underline

            rectPaint.setColor(underlineColor);
            canvas.drawRect(0, height - underlineHeight, tabsContainer.getWidth(), height, rectPaint);

            // draw divider

            dividerPaint.setColor(dividerColor);
            for (int i = 0; i < tabCount - 1; i++) {
                View tab = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
                canvas.drawLine(tab.getRight(), dividerPadding, tab.getRight(), height - dividerPadding, dividerPaint);
            }
        }

        private class PageListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                currentPosition = position;
                currentPositionOffset = positionOffset;

                scrollToChild(position, (int) (positionOffset * tabsContainer.getChildAt(position).getWidth()));

                invalidate();

                if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                    delegatePageListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    scrollToChild(pager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
                }

                if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                    delegatePageListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (delegatePageListener != null) {
                    delegatePageListener.onPageSelected(position);
                }
            }

        }

        public void setIndicatorColor(int indicatorColor) {
            this.indicatorColor = indicatorColor;
            invalidate();
        }

        public void setIndicatorColorResource(int resId) {
            this.indicatorColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getIndicatorColor() {
            return this.indicatorColor;
        }

        public void setIndicatorHeight(int indicatorLineHeightPx) {
            this.indicatorHeight = indicatorLineHeightPx;
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getIndicatorHeight() {
            return indicatorHeight;
        }

        public void setUnderlineColor(int underlineColor) {
            this.underlineColor = underlineColor;
            invalidate();
        }

        public void setUnderlineColorResource(int resId) {
            this.underlineColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getUnderlineColor() {
            return underlineColor;
        }

        public void setDividerColor(int dividerColor) {
            this.dividerColor = dividerColor;
            invalidate();
        }

        public void setDividerColorResource(int resId) {
            this.dividerColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getDividerColor() {
            return dividerColor;
        }

        public void setUnderlineHeight(int underlineHeightPx) {
            this.underlineHeight = underlineHeightPx;
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getUnderlineHeight() {
            return underlineHeight;
        }

        public void setDividerPadding(int dividerPaddingPx) {
            this.dividerPadding = dividerPaddingPx;
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getDividerPadding() {
            return dividerPadding;
        }

        public void setScrollOffset(int scrollOffsetPx) {
            this.scrollOffset = scrollOffsetPx;
            invalidate();
        }

        public int getScrollOffset() {
            return scrollOffset;
        }

        public void setShouldExpand(boolean shouldExpand) {
            this.shouldExpand = shouldExpand;
            requestLayout();
        }

        public boolean getShouldExpand() {
            return shouldExpand;
        }

        public boolean isTextAllCaps() {
            return textAllCaps;
        }

        public void setAllCaps(boolean textAllCaps) {
            this.textAllCaps = textAllCaps;
        }

        public void setTextSize(int textSizePx) {
            this.tabTextSize = textSizePx;
            updateTabStyles();
        }

        public int getTextSize() {
            return tabTextSize;
        }

        public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
            this.tabTextColor = textColor;
            updateTabStyles();
        }

        public void setTextColorResource(int resId) {
            this.tabTextColor = getResources().getColor(resId);
            updateTabStyles();
        }

        public int getTextColor() {
            return tabTextColor;
        }

        public void setTypeface(Typeface typeface, int style) {
            this.tabTypeface = typeface;
            this.tabTypefaceStyle = style;
            updateTabStyles();
        }

        public void setTabBackground(int resId) {
            this.tabBackgroundResId = resId;
        }

        public int getTabBackground() {
            return tabBackgroundResId;
        }

        public void setTabPaddingLeftRight(int paddingPx) {
            this.tabPadding = paddingPx;
            updateTabStyles();
        }

        public int getTabPaddingLeftRight() {
            return tabPadding;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
            SavedState savedState = (SavedState) state;
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState.getSuperState());
            currentPosition = savedState.currentPosition;
            requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
            Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();
            SavedState savedState = new SavedState(superState);
            savedState.currentPosition = currentPosition;
            return savedState;
        }

        static class SavedState extends BaseSavedState {
            int currentPosition;

            public SavedState(Parcelable superState) {
                super(superState);
            }

            private SavedState(Parcel in) {
                super(in);
                currentPosition = in.readInt();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
                super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);
                dest.writeInt(currentPosition);
            }

            public static final Parcelable.Creator<SavedState> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SavedState>() {
                @Override
                public SavedState createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                    return new SavedState(in);
                }

                @Override
                public SavedState[] newArray(int size) {
                    return new SavedState[size];
                }
            };
        }

    }
```

values/attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="PagerSlidingTabStrip">
        <attr name="pstsIndicatorColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsUnderlineColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsDividerColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="pstsIndicatorHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsUnderlineHeight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsDividerPadding" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsTabPaddingLeftRight" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsScrollOffset" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="pstsTabBackground" format="reference" />
        <attr name="pstsShouldExpand" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="pstsTextAllCaps" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

Comment: you are a victim of **typos** . i think

Comment: @jankigadhiya my app without export signed `debug` good work. but export with signed apk lead to this error. I check my spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 8):

I also Met the same problem so i solved by

set

> @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")

at your class PagerSlidingTabStrip

> @SuppressWarnings("ResourceType") 
>   public class PagerSlidingTabStrip
>   extends HorizontalScrollView { ..... }

and in your gradle under default config :

> lintOptions {
>               disable "ResourceType"
>
> ```
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem when try to build signed apk. 
And then I add these line to file lint.xml:

```
<lint>
    <issue id="ResourceType" severity="Warning" />
</lint>
```

the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your attrs.xml everything is defined. Also, check for typos, in both your java class, and the xml file. Android, is telling you what is wrong. If you still cant find the error, look at your logcat and filter by errors.